# getting string image path placed in drawable folder

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the path of an image in string form in android like

res/drawable/image.png

Or is their any other way for getting string path of an image that is placed in drawable.

Comment: why you want that path in string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.

```
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

e.g. will give you the default launcher icon. It is not possible to get the exact path for an image , that is stored in drawable.

**Why not?** When you compile your app to an *.apk file, all resources (ok, except from them in /raw) are compiled as well. You can only acces them, using their R. id.

**Solution?** Not really, you could copy them to a location on the sd card for example. Now you know the location :)

Answer (score 2):

its not possible to get path of drawable image directly , but you can get this by storing it in internal memory or sdcard of device.For this i have written blog.. check out the link
[here](http://maulik-dhameliya.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-drawable.html)

i am sure it will help you.

Comment: nope - for copying the resources to an external storage you first must know the path to put them in. this creates a circular problem - you must know the path to put a resource on SD in order to know the path. the whole process is pointless. also your "solution" does not cover the case of devices with no SD storage or non-removable storage.

Comment: I am saying that if you have any images in drawable and you want to use its path in code , you want be able to do that. so for that you just copy image at particular location in internal storage if you dont have sd card. i am not forcefully saying you to use SD card.